# Oracle timestamp to sql server DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, datetime

I have multiple statements from oracle database and I need to use them in SQL Server

```
insert into COMENZI (NR_COMANDA, DATA, MODALITATE, ID_CLIENT, STARE_COMANDA, ID_ANGAJAT)
values (2456, to_timestamp('08-11-1998 07:53:25.989889', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'direct', 117, 0, 163);

insert into COMENZI (NR_COMANDA, DATA, MODALITATE, ID_CLIENT, STARE_COMANDA, ID_ANGAJAT)
values (2457, to_timestamp('01-11-1999 09:22:16.162632', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff'), 'direct', 118, 5, 159);
```

How can I create a function to_timestamp that returns a DateTime with the given value?

Comment: The answer depends on how you are talking to the databases?  Is this part of an application (.net, ColdFusion, etc)?  Are you using linked servers?

Comment: Nope, you're going to far - I just created the same table schema, because I have the scripts.. and I want to execute them in SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in SQL Server 2008 ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34455)):

```
select convert(datetime, left(t, 10), 105) +
       convert(time, substring(t, 12, 12), 114)
from (select '01-11-1999 09:22:16.162632' as t) t;
```

Ironically, it doesn't work in SQL Server 2012.  There, I think you have to do:

```
select dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, 0,  convert(datetime, substring(t, 12, 12), 114)),
               convert(datetime, left(t, 10), 105)
              )
from (select '01-11-1999 09:22:16.162632' as t) t;
```

Note in both cases, this uses milliseconds rather than microseconds.  I don't believe SQL Server offers date time value with that much precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this statement

```
select convert(datetime, left(t, 10), 105) +
       convert(time, substring(t, 12, 12), 114)
from (select '01-11-1999 09:22:16.162632' as t) t;
```

into

```
select convert(datetime, left(t, 10), 105) +
       convert(datetime, substring(t, 12, 12), 114)
from (select '01-11-1999 09:22:16.162632' as t) t;
```

it will work correct with all SQL-Server versions

The error that **datetime** and **time** are incompatible types in the **add-operator** occurs only in SQL-Server 2012.